# How to store HTML Elements as global variable in the console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

When I use chrome developper tools, for any variable that I logged to the console using `console.log`, I can right-click and select `Store as global variable`, except if I log a HTML Element.

I found a workaround: if using `console.log([el])` instead of `console.log(el)`, it is possible to save the array to a global variable and then use `temp1[0]` to access the element.

This seems somehow cumbersome. Is there another way to store a `console.log`ged element in a global variable in the console ?

Comment: Maybe `debugger;` helps a bit? Then the script will stop there and you can use all the variables of the current scope in the console. Otherwise you can store variables in the window object like `windows.foo = someBar;`.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  When you find the element you could simply set a variable there and then (using `window.` if not in global scope)

Comment: _"for any variable that I logged to the console using console.log, I can right-click and select Store as global variable"_ Can  you include the necessary steps to reproduce at the Question?

Comment: @guest271314 I already included the necessary steps: (1) log to the console using console.log, (2) right-click and select Store as global variable

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$$(selector)`

```
ƒ $$(selector, [startNode]) { [Command Line API] }
```

then use the procedure described at the Question.

Comment: What does this mean ? I can't understand your answer.

Comment: What is `$$`? Are you using mootools ?!

Comment: No, that is part of the [Command Line API Reference](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference?) _"`$$(selector)` returns an array of elements that match the given CSS selector."_ You can then right-click and select `Store as global variable`

Comment: Thanks for the link to the Command Line API Reference. This is really interesting, and there are many features that I was not aware of.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer You can alternatively use `console.dir()` to achieve the same requirement. `var el = document.body; console.dir(el)`

Answer (score 0):

`$_` returns the last logged item in the console.
Beware, though, that it might return `undefined` if you use `console.log()`, because if you do `console.log('hi!');`, then it will also return `undefined`. To workaround:

```
/*just type value instead of console.log*/
'hello!';
var text=$_;
/*If you cannot do this, just log it in this way:*/
x.valueOf();
var xContent=$_;
```